# Why doesn't the animation speed parameter take my variable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I need the variable 'gv' to have the value of a button, i did this with this.value and it worked as alerts give the right values. but once i gave that variable to the speed parameter of an animation, it didn't work.

i tried giving the variable right at the animation, but that didn't work either. i also tried to give the animation random value's to see if it was effected, and it was. but the variable doesn't do anything at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var GV = this.value;
    $("#ball").animate({
      bottom: "0px"
    }, GV);
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ball"></div>
<button value="18999" class="btn">butt on</button>
```

i expect the animation to pull the div to the bottom at the speed of 18999 milliseconds, but it pulls at 800 milliseconds

Comment: Because the function is expecting a number or keyword, you have passed in some text that doesn't match any keyword - try using `parseInt(GV)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.value` is a string. According to [JQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) the strings allowed for `animate()` method parameters are 'fast' or 'slow'. Any other string will be disregarded and the default speed will be used. Use `parseInt($(this).val())` to get the integer value of the button element:

```
var GV = parseInt($(this).val());
```

Comment: If you are using JQuery why not use it all the way to ensure future compatibility. `this.value` isn't JQuery, it's plain old javascript.

Comment: welcome @syter. it's great language and you'll enjoy it

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to parse your GV value as integer (`this.value` is a string):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
       let GV = $(this).val();
       console.log(GV);
      $("#ball").animate({
        bottom: "0px"
      }, parseInt(GV));
    })
  });
```

Code to try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var GV = this.value;
    console.log(GV);
    $("#ball").animate({
      bottom: "0px"
    }, parseInt(GV));
  })
});
```

```css
#ball {
  background-color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ball"></div>
<button value="18999" class="btn">button</button>
```